VS Code Extension TreeView: Selecting Many On First Click
I'm working on a VS Code extension right now that uses a TreeDataProvider to display versions of an application. None of the TreeItems use a command directly -- they're used through the context when two versions are selected.
It all works fine -- however, When I'm using ctrl+click to select each TreeItem, to select a second version, I have to click it twice.  I'd like to avoid this. Is this possible?
